# Get only necessary constructor property within a called function

Tags: javascript, constructor, properties

I'm quite new concerning constructor functions.

For personal purposes, I'm making a script that extends the possibilities of the Date() object.

But when I create an object with `new` and asking for a specific property, all properties are processed (as I can see in the console actually). How to avoid that to save some resources ?

For example, if I do : `var bisextile = new RightTime(2022).IsBisextile`, I don't want `RightTime().NextFullMoon` being calculated.

Thanks

```
const RightTime = function(a,m,j,h,min) {
  var getLunarAge = function(d,b,c) {
    d = void 0 === a ? new Date() : new Date(d,b,c);
    var b = d.getTime();
    d = d.getTimezoneOffset();
    b = (b / 86400000 - d / 1440 - 10962.6) / 29.530588853;
    b -= Math.floor(b);
    0 > b && (b += 1);
    return 29.530588853 * b;
  };
  var woy = function(yy,mm,dd) {
    var date = new Date(yy,mm-1,dd);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3 - (date.getDay() + 6) % 7);
    var week1 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 4);
    return 1 + Math.round(((date.getTime() - week1.getTime()) / 86400000 - 3 + (week1.getDay() + 6) % 7) / 7);
  };

  a || m || j || h || min ? (!m && (m = 1), !j && (j = 1), !h && (h = 0), !min && (min = 0), this.Now = new Date(a, m - 1, j, h, min)) : this.Now = new Date()
  this.Day = this.Now.getDate();
  this.DayInWeek = 0 == this.Now.getDay() ? 7 : this.Now.getDay();
  this.DayInWeekName = days[this.DayInWeek];
  this.Year = this.Now.getFullYear();
  this.IsBissextile = ((this.Year % 4 === 0 && this.Year % 100 > 0) || (this.Year % 400 === 0));  
  this.Month = this.Now.getMonth() + 1;
  // (...)
  this.MoonAge = getLunarAge(this.Year, this.Month, this.Day); 
  this.NextFullMoon = this.MoonAge > 14.765294427 ? 44.29588328 - this.MoonAge : 14.765294427 - this.MoonAge;
  this.NextNewMoon = 29.530588853 - this.MoonAge;
  var mn = Math.round((this.MoonAge * 8) / 29.530588853)
 // (...)
  this.ShiftDays = function(n) {
    let d = new Date(this.Year,this.Month-1,this.Day);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + n);
    return d
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case the "saving of resources" is negligible. We're talking about a few bytes of memory. But if you're worried put all the other calculations in a separate function(s) and call them when they're needed. You might also [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#field_declarations) a more modern approach to your code.

Comment: Yes I intend to add a lot more of calculations. And calendars are going to be generated from this function with some recursions. When you say "separate functions", you mean outside of the RightTime() function ? Or it doesn't matter ? Thank you about your advice about ``class``. Gonna check right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might utilize [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

**Example**

```js
const RightTime = function(a,m,j,h,min) {
  
  this.Now = new Date()
  this.Year = this.Now.getFullYear();
  
  Object.assign(this, {
    get IsBissextile() {
      return (this.Year % 4 === 0 && this.Year % 100 > 0) || (this.Year % 400 === 0)
    }
  })
}

const test = new RightTime();

console.log(test.IsBissextile);
```

Or use modern `class` as [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377002/andy) recommended

**Example**

```js
class RightTime {
  constructor(a,m,j,h,min) {
    this.Now = new Date()
    this.Year = this.Now.getFullYear();
    this.Month = this.Now.getMonth() + 1;
  }

  get IsBissextile() {
    return (this.Year % 4 === 0 && this.Year % 100 > 0) || (this.Year % 400 === 0)
  }
  
  get Zodiac() {
    const zodiacEmote = {
      12: "♐",
    };
    const month = this.Month;
    
    return {
      get Emote() {
        return zodiacEmote[month];
      }
    }
  }
}

const test = new RightTime();

console.log(test.IsBissextile);
console.log(test.Zodiac.Emote);
```

As for the `saving resources`, I don't know how did you draw the conclusion but usually it would be better to run js profiler and see there potential culprits.

Comment: Thank you. Except getter doesn't accept any arguments. And functions inside a class throws : ``unexpected token: identifier``. And I need arguments for some properties like : ```ShiftDays = (n) => {
    let d = new Date(this.Year,this.Month-1,this.Day);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + n);
    return new RightTime(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getDate())
  }```

Comment: Yeah you cant use getter for that scenario, `ShiftDays` has to be a routine.

Comment: It seems to be okay ;) with ``get`` I see no trace of other parameters when I don't call them. Thanks !

Comment: What if I want to nest properties ?
``Zodiac = () => {
   this.Emote = () => { return zodiacEmote[this.Month] }
}
console.log(new RightTime().Zodiac.Emote)`` This is not working. Nor another class within the parent one, nor ``getter``

Comment: Updated answer. I would keep information about zodiacs in separate class though.